# Has anyone ever hacked into a traffic control system to change the stoplights?

Tags: technology, computers, hacking

This is a relatively common trope with regards to the powers of hackers in film: Someone hacks into the "Traffic Control Center" and gains instant access to all stoplights in an area. This includes the option of turning everything red; everything green; etc. *Hackers*, *Italian Job*, *Live Free or Die Hard* are examples that come to mind.

Has anyone ever done something like this? Is it possible?

Comment: Didn't I read a story where a fire department could turn all the lights red along the route they will be taking to the fire?  Whatever system does that might be a target for hackers.

Comment: I personally heard Defcon 22 presentation which explained that it is (or was) possible. Here is reporting on it: http://www.scmagazine.com/defcon-traffic-control-systems-vulnerable-to-hacking/article/365416/ The materials themselves are surely available online somewhere. Not sure if the situation changed since then, probably not everywhere, so I would estimate at least some traffic systems may be still vulnerable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's two versions of this: a hardware hack and a software hack.

The hardware hack (otherwise known as [DIrtY MIRT,](http://www.i-hacked.com/content/view/176/44/) aka "Do It Yourself Mobile Infra Red Transmitter") is definitely doable and possible, as they are both being built, [sold](http://www.bikeforums.net/archive/index.php/t-269356.html), and even [having laws passed prohibiting their sale/usage](http://www.wired.com/science/discoveries/news/2005/08/68507).

As far as software hacks, this was also done:

http://articles.latimes.com/2007/jan/09/local/me-trafficlights9

> officials now allege that two engineers, Kartik Patel and Gabriel Murillo, figured out how to hack in anyway. With a few clicks on a laptop computer, the pair -- one a renowned traffic engineer profiled in the national media, the other a computer whiz who helped build the system -- allegedly tied up traffic at four intersections for several days.

<strike>http://weirdwebtoday.com/?p=412</strike><sup>*</sup>

> Transportation bosses in the Netherlands are trying to find out who hacked the traffic-light computer system to show a couple making love when the lights turned green.
>
> The altered lights in Nijmegen, Holland, stopped traffic when passersby kept pressing the pedestrian buttons to see the couple having doggie-style sex on the green light, the Austrian Times reports.

<sup>* Dead link. Dutch regional news item on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qewWW-mSua0</sup>

Comment: Heh, wow: "They didn't shut the lights off [... they] programmed them so that red lights would be extremely long." +1, certainly. I will leave this open for a day just for posterity but this completely answers the question.

Comment: Looking at the picture and some other reports about that Dutch "hack", it seems this is not a software hack but just a replacement of the sticker in front of the pedestrian traffic light.

Comment: As for the software "hack", this seems that the engineers had proper *technical* authorization in the system ("user `someuser` can alter light patterns"), but they made the modification without a *legal* order to do so, or even despite an order not to do so. So, while *technically possible*, such insider jobs are much less glamorous than a bunch of eveeel haxx0rz driving up with a laptop and changing the lights as they see fit - if I were working in a datacenter, it would be trivial to shut it down with one of the SCRAM buttons, but that's hardly "hacking in". Access is 90% of the obstacles.